# specflow project: how to pass current directory to ChromeOptions

Tags: c#, specflow

Had to switch from Java to C# and still struggling a bit. For example, when I'm running

```
driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver();
```

I'm getting error: "The chromedriver.exe file does not exist in the current directory or in a directory on the PATH environment variable."

I can work this around by passing the current directory to the driver:

```
driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
```

However, when I need to run chrome headless, I am passing ChromeOptions like this:

```
 options.AddArgument("headless");

 driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver(options);
```

So, the question is, how do I pass Environment.CurrentDirectory to ChromeOptions so it is passed to the ChromeDriver?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

```
driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.
                ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(path),options);
```